# Unknown type in NuxtApp type when provide pocketbase

Tags: typescript, plugins, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pocketbase

As defined in this page https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#typing-plugins

When I add a provider to useNuxtApp it will be auto type. But actually I have a problem where my $pb in useNuxtApp() is unknown type in place of PocketBase type.

If I check in my plugins file pocketBase the provider return if the correct PocketBase type but I don't understand why I want access to it in $pb it's unknown.

Have you any solution?

```js
// composables/useUserStore.ts
export const useUserStore = ()=>{

  const loginWithEmailAndPassword = async (email:string,password:string)=>{
    return await useNuxtApp().$pb.collection('users').authWithPassword(email,password)
  }
}
```

```js
// plugins/pocketbase.ts
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
  const pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090');

  const cookie = useCookie<{token:string,model:any}>("pb_auth", {
    path:     "/",
    secure:   true,
    sameSite: "strict",
    httpOnly: false, // change to "true" if you want only server-side access
    maxAge:   604800,
  })

  // load the store data from the cookie value
  pb.authStore.save(cookie.value?.token, cookie.value?.model);

  // send back the default 'pb_auth' cookie to the client with the latest store state
  pb.authStore.onChange(() => {
    console.log(pb.authStore.model)
    cookie.value = {
      token: pb.authStore.token,
      model: pb.authStore.model,
    };
  },true);

  try {
      // get an up-to-date auth store state by verifying and refreshing the loaded auth model (if any)
      pb.authStore.isValid && await pb.collection('users').authRefresh();
  } catch (_) {
      // clear the auth store on failed refresh
      pb.authStore.clear();
  }

  return {
    provide: { pb }
  }
});
```